# Сделать метод, принимающий лямбду

Tags: c++, lambda

Сделал тип указателя на функцию:

```
typedef bool (*BreakFunc)(IReader *reader);
```

Некоторый класс имеет метод, принимающий в качестве параметра указатель на функцию типа BreakFunc. Он выглядит так:

```
GaugeReader::addBreakFunc(BreakFunc func);
```

В методе другого класса я вызываю функцию `addBreakFunc` так:

```
CalibProcedure::setBreakpoints()
{
    GaugeReader r;
    r.addBreakFunc([](IReader *reader){
        return false;
    });
}
```

Такой код работает без проблем, пока в лямбде не появляются захваченные переменные. В таком случае компилятор сообщает, что не может найти подходящую функцию `addBreakFunc`. То есть захваченные переменные так повлияли на лямбду, что она перестала соответствовать типу `BreakFunc`. Почему так произошло? Есть ли другие, более правильные способы заставить метод `addBreakFunc` принимать лямбду?

Используется C++ 11. Уверен, что правильные способы существуют, так как такие функции есть в библиотеке Qt, например, `QtConcurrent::run(тут лямбда)`, однако в куче прототипов я не нашёл тот, который нужен.

Может быть есть средства Qt, позволяющие решить эту задачу?

Comment: GaugeReader::addBreakFunc(std::function<bool(IReader *)> _func);

Comment: Вариант с std::function работает, но ответы всё ещё принимаются. Интересует, есть ли аналогичные классы в Qt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот пример передачи лямбды в качестве аргумента функции. Вероятно, вам нужно именно это. Работает в C++11 и в C++14.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

void invoke(std::function<int (int)> fun){
    int res = fun(123);
    printf("result: %d \n", res);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    auto fun1 = [=](int x) { return x * a; };
    auto fun2 = [&](int x) { return x * a; };

    invoke(fun1);
    invoke(fun2);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Тип лямбда-выражения - это объект некоторого анонимного класса.
Если лямбда-выражение не захватывает переменные, то у этого класса есть оператор преобразования к указателю на функцию, иначе - нету.

Другими словами - если есть такая возможность, не используйте указатели на функцию, или передавайте нужные переменные как-то еще.

Comment: Добавлю — вместо указателя здесь нужно использовать либо `std::function`, либо делать метод, принимающий лямбду, шаблонным..

Answer (score 6):

Ваши предположения верны, так делать нельзя.

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

> A lambda can only be converted to a function pointer **if it does not
>   capture**, from the [draft C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) section 5.1.2.**6**
>   [expr.prim.lambda] says (emphasis mine):
>
> > *The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a
> >     public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer
> >     to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure
> >     type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
> >     function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
> >     the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.*

Можно использовать `std::function`

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать шаблоны.

```
template <typename F>
GaugeReader::addBreakFunc(F func);
```

Comment: А почему никто не плюсует? Правильный ответ же.

Comment: @VladD, ответ, бесспорно, правильный, но реализовывать метод `addBreakFunc` в этом случае придётся в заголовочном файле. Мне бы не хотелось этого делать.

Comment: @maestro: Почему не хотелось бы? С шаблонами вам всё равно придётся такое делать — вы ведь не избегаете шаблонов в вашей программе?

Comment: @VladD, нет, я не избегаю шаблонов, они в программе присутствуют. Просто заголовочный файл в этом случае (для меня) выглядит засорённым. Возможно, это связанно с тем, что я не научился правильно их использовать, ведь описания шаблонов в книгах и статьях интернета обычно ограничиваются парой примеров. Вот [пример одного использования шаблонов в моём коде](http://alouette.su/page/udalenie-elementa-iz-vektora-po-tipu). Это правильное (оправданное) их использование или есть другой путь добиться того же эффекта? p.s. Возможно, лучше перейти в чат, но я не знаю как.

Comment: @maestro: Не, вы правы, в этом случае header выглядит ужасно засорённо. Но это проблема самого языка, так что я привык с ней мириться.