# C++ лямбда захват

Tags: c++, lambda

Как захватить f?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    int i=444;
public:
    void(*f)(int)=0;

    void r()
    {
        f(i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int f=3;

    test t;

    t.f=[&f](int i){cout<<i<<' '<<f;}; //////!!!!!!!

    t.r();

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка...

```
./Playground/file0.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./Playground/file0.cpp:22:32: error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda(int)>' to 'void (*)(int)' in assignment
   22 |     t.f=[&f](int i){cout<<i<<' '<<f;};
```

Comment: Она уже захватывается, ничего делать не нужно.

Comment: ошибку выдает когда пишу &f, когда убераю его, то такая ошибка ./Playground/file0.cpp: In lambda function:
./Playground/file0.cpp:22:28: error: 'f' is not captured
   22 |     t.f=[](int i){cout<<i<<f;};

Comment: Ну правильно, `&f` - это собственно и есть захват.

Comment: Мне ошибку выдает!!!! Там написано же. Что вы издеваетесь?

Comment: Да, но в плане захвата переменной синтаксис правильный. К захвату ошибка не имеет отношения. Если у вас вопрос про ошибку, а не про захват, то создавайте новый вопрос с соотв. заголовоком

Comment: А как сделать то? Чтобы ошибок не выдавало? Я и сам думаю, что правильный, а что с того? Оно не компилируется.

Comment: когда я убераю код связанный с захватом, то ошибка исчезает, значит она связана с захватом

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562106/3380

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А с чего вы решили, что лямбда имеет тип `void(*)(int)`?! Лямбда с захватом - это совсем не функция!

Попробуйте так.

```
#include <functional>
class test
{
    int i=444;
public:
    function<void(int)> f = 0;

    void r()
    {
        f(i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int f=3;

    test t;

    t.f=[&f](int i){cout<<i<<' '<<f;}; //////!!!!!!!

    t.r();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, у кого тут комплекс неполноценности, выражающийся в анонимном минусовании? :) Ты уж будь мужчиной, выскажись в лицо :)

Comment: Лямбда с захватом это функциональный объект?

function это что? Оно не объявлено. Нужно заголовок подключить?

Comment: #include <functional>

Comment: @LuaКолдун А как вы себе представляете функцию - с захватом переменной? **Куда** она захватывается?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    int i = 444;
public:
    void(*f)(void*) = nullptr;

    void r()
    {
        int* h = &i;
        f(h);
    }
};

struct Lambda {
    template<typename Tret, typename T>
    static Tret lambda_ptr_exec(void* data) {
        return (Tret)(*(T*)fn<T>())(data);
    }

    template<typename Tret = void, typename Tfp = Tret(*)(void*), typename T>
    static Tfp ptr(T& t) {
        fn<T>(&t);
        return (Tfp)lambda_ptr_exec<Tret, T>;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void* fn(void* new_fn = nullptr) {
        static void* fn;
        if (new_fn != nullptr)
            fn = new_fn;
        return fn;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int f = 3;

    test t;
    auto b = [&f](void* i) {cout << *((int*)(i)) << ' ' << f; };
    t.f = Lambda::ptr(b); //////!!!!!!!

    t.r();

     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а какой тип данных у b?

Comment: @LuaКолдун вы его не сможете использовать, тут только auto подойдет